# why input field is not render in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to parse Object to render HTML element . I am not able to show any HTML element. I think there is some `return` statement problem in my code

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sun-i3vy4i?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({
      [e.event.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  const expractCompont = (component) => {
    switch (component.type) {
      case "textfield":
        return (
          <>
            <label>{component.label}</label>
            <input type="text" name={component.id} onchange={handleChange} />
          </>
        );

      case "number":
        return (
          <>
            <label>{component.label}</label>
            <input type="number" name={component.id} onchange={handleChange} />
          </>
        );

      case "select":
        return (
          <>
            <label>{component.label}</label>
            <select name={component.id} id={component.id}>
              {component.values.map((item, index) => (
                <option value={item.value} key={index}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <input
              type="number"
              name={component.field_107we45}
              onchange={handleChange}
            />
          </>
        );
      default:
        return <></>;
    }
  };

  const renderComponents = (components) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < components.length; index++) {
      const element = components[index];
      expractCompont(element);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {renderComponents(data.components)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Expected output** :
Expected output to see input fields ,select box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `renderComponents` function returns nothing. You need to return an array from it.

```js
  const renderComponents = (components) => {
    const elementsToRender = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < components.length; index++) {
      const element = components[index];
      elementsToRender.push(expractCompont(element))
    }
    return elementsToRender;
  };
```

Actually, the `renderComponents` function is not really needed, you can put everything at once in return

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {data.components.map(expractCompont)}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: if possible can you please share code sandox

Comment: @naveensharma Is it still relevant? I looked at your sandbox and it looks like you did fine

Answer (score 0):

You can just update your `renderComponents` to this and it will work fine

```
  const renderComponents = (components) => {
    return components.map(expractCompont)
  };
```